# How do I make this change method, so I get the bills for that given amount

Tags: javascript

I have this task where I have to divide the given amount of money into bills. I can't see what I'm doing wrong and therefore asking for some guidance.

```
export function change(amount) {

    var bills = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000];
    var result = [];

    while (amount > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < bills.length; i++) {
            if (amount >= bills[i]) {
                amount -= bills[i];
                result.push(bills[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return result.length;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider tagging your question with the relevant tags.  Spamming tags isn't productive.   That said,  your bills[] array starts with 1..  perhaps reversing your bills array might be helpful?

Comment: That said,  please post your input,  your actual output and the expected output.

Comment: Break out of the **for** loop if the `if` statement condition is true. Oh...and set your bills array in descending order instead of ascending as you have now.

Comment: @DevilsHnd i don't think that's the solution

Comment: You might want to try iterating through `bills` backwards since you want to try the bigger bills first instead of starting at 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code checks the smaller bills before it checks the larger bills, which is clearly wrong: you want to have as many $1000 bills as possible before you resort to using $1 bills. So, you can reverse your bills array, or just sort it so it's reversed:

```js
function change(amount) {
    const bills = [1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
    // alternatively, to sort it
    // bills.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    const result = [];
    for (const bill of bills) {
        const billCount = Math.floor(amount / bill);
        amount = amount % bill;
        result.push(...new Array(billCount).fill(bill));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current problem with your code lies in the fact that it always goes with the *first* bill, not the largest. You need to find the largest bill that can fit for a given amount to minimize the number of bills needed.

Let's say you try `change(100)` using your current code. It will evaluate bill 1, see that it fits, and moves on to bill 2, which of course also fits. Your current program will repeat `bills` as the output until it reaches the target value.

You can fix this by iterating through `bills` backwards (starting from the largest), or you can simply reverse it and keep your current code.

Here's a slightly touched up version that fixes the bug and uses some nice modern JS features.

```js
const change = function(amount) {

    const bills = [1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1];
    const result = [];

    while(amount > 0) {
        for(const bill of bills) {
            if(amount >= bill) {
                amount -= bill;
                result.push(bill);              
            }
        }
    }

    // You don't mention what the expected return value is, so completing this function is up to you
    // (...)
    
};
```

Comment: `const bill` > `let bill` :p. also outer `while` is redundant if you change the inner `if` into a while. and of course the result value is very clear in the OP so using an array (and subtracting bills one by one!) is a bit overkill. also `const name = anonymous function` is kinda ew

Comment: @somebody I intentionally kept the outer while loop to keep the code similar to OP's, but I would agree that they should go with your suggestion

Comment: anyway either way i don't think `const change = function` is a "modern js feature". and of course I think `const` is a more proper "modern js feature" to use than `let`, since you're using a "new feature" anyway

Comment: @somebody IMO defining function as an anonymous const is kind of nice since it prevents modification afterwards, but it's really a matter of preference. I edited the post to change the inner `let` to `const`, though

Comment: also consider that OP is exporting anyway so you'd probably want that syntax anyway

Answer (score -2):

I made this code you can refactor this if you want but I think this will do

```js
function change (amount) {
  let change = {}
  let bills = [1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]

  if (amount > 0) {
     bills.map(bill => {
       if(amount > 0 && amount >= bill) {
          let value = amount / bill

          if(amount % bill == 0) {
            change[bill.toString()] = value

            amount -= value * bill

            return
          }

          let remainder = amount % bill

          change[bill.toString()] = ((value * bill) - remainder) / bill

          amount = remainder
       }
     });
  }

  return change
}

this.change(111)
```

Comment: This: doesn't work, is hacky, and returns strings when numbers should be used.

Comment: @Aplet123 hi. also yea among other stuff like inconsistent semicolons. and yeah not only is it hacky, it's way more unreadable than the proper way

Comment: @Aplet123 what do you mean by hacky?

Comment: You're converting numbers to strings then performing string manipulation on them then converting them back into numbers. Not only is this unintuitive, it's inconsistent (due to floating point imprecision) and slow.

Comment: @Aplet123 Hi, I change my code a little bit you think this may work?